# Proving that $dT=0$ at every point implies locally constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Prove: If T is of class $C^2$ on an open set $D$, and $dT=0$ at each point in $D$, then $T$ is locally constant.

Unfortunately this problem comes from Buck, where they love to omit notation. So I assume this is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My solution is simply,  fix $p \in D$, then we can find a "square" neighborhood $(p_i-q_i,p_i+q_i)_{1\le i \le n} \subset D$ (apologies for this notational confusion). Proceeding one dimension at a time, fix $x \in (p_1-q_1,p_1+q_1)\times(p_2,p_3,\cdots,p_n)$ and we can show using the mean value theorem that $T(x)=T(p)$ (because $dT=0$, we have that all the partials are zero on all of $D$). Then repeating for the 2nd dimension, we can show the same for every point in $(p_1-q_1,p_1+q_1)\times(p_2-q_2,p_2+q_2)\times(p_3,\cdots,p_n)$. The repeating for each dimension we can show the same for every point in $(p_i-q_i,p_i+q_i)_{1\le i \le n}$. Thus we have a neighborhood on which $T$ is locally constant.

So the first question is, why does $T$ need to be $C^2$? Isn't only $C^1$ needed for the one-dimensional mean value theorem? Second, is there a more concise way to proceed in this proof? Something which would handle all the dimensions at once instead of iteratively using mean value theorem. (I guess the third question is, is the above proof a valid way to proceed on this problem?)

Comment: The book states *of class* $C''$. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Siminore - My impression was that this notation means $C^2$. $C=C^0$, $C'=C^1$, $C''=C^2$, etc. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: No, but it seems strange since the authors never use second derivatives when introducing the MVT.